# Wrap image in word document using OpenXml SDK

Tags: ms-word, word-wrap, openxml-sdk

Is there a way to add a new text wrapping type to an image (for example set the wrap option of the image as "Tight") in a word document using OpenXml SDK where the wrap option of the image is already set as "Behind Text"?